# MYSQL shows vague syntax error despite everything being seemingly accurate

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

This was the MYSQL query:

`` ALTER TABLE` locations`
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_UserCheck 
FOREIGN KEY PersonID REFERENCES `user`(id) ``

The Error I got back:

`` #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCES `user`(id)' at line 3 ``

What seems to be the error in syntax over here?

Using:

> MYSQL
>
> MYPHPADMIN Version 5.0.1**

Comment: Of course there;s an error. you are naming a foreign key but not naming the column to be used as a reference to another table also ` locations` the leading spaces looks dubious. Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: I removed the leading spaces but PersonId is the column that refers to the column id in the table user tho?

Comment: Yup read the manual.

Comment: Enclose PersonId  inside parentheses: `ALTER TABLE locations
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_UserCheck
FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES user(id)`

Comment: yess thank you I just checked the syntax and got this